# connecting phpadmin to remote database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to conncet the local phpadmin to remote database but it says error. Error says "Cannot log in to the MySQL server".

Below is the config.inc.php file for phpadmin.

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'database_user_1'; //database user name
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root'; //database user 1 password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '208.91.198.231';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

I tried to reinstall the xampp and reconnected now i am able to login to local mysql database, but when tring to connect to remote server it says below error.

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
```

Any suggestion how to solve the issue.

Comment: remote sql server allows connections?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your versions against the requirements; that error message suggests that your phpMyAdmin requires MySQL 5.5 or newer but your host is using an older version. Check the phpMyAdmin [download page](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/), where there's a brief list of supported phpMyAdmin versions and their requirements (or of course, the "Requirements" section of the corresponding manual). For MySQL less than 5.5, phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.10 is the currently suggested version.